# SQL Server CTE puzzle

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to generate seven consecutive dates using CTE. I am wondering why the following code works:

```
DECLARE @from DATE = '20160911', @to DATE = '20160917';

WITH seven_consecutive_dates AS 
(
    SELECT @from date

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, scd.date) 
    FROM seven_consecutive_dates scd 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, scd.date) <= @to
)
SELECT * 
FROM seven_consecutive_dates
```

?

and the following doesn't:

```
DECLARE @from DATE = '20160911', @to DATE = '20160917';

WITH seven_consecutive_dates AS  
(
    SELECT @from date

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, scd.date) 
    FROM seven_consecutive_dates scd 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, scd.date), @to) < 6
)
SELECT * 
FROM seven_consecutive_dates
```

What if I had only starting or ending date? How shall I enforce generation of SEVEN consecutive dates?

Comment: Because for dates prior to @to, the datediff is less than 6, and it gradually decreases (into negative numbers) because the first date grows. e.g. datediff(day, tomorrow, today) is -1, datediff(day, two days from now, today) is -2, etc. Negative numbers are less than 6. To fix it, change the `< 6` to `>= 0`.

Comment: Just add it to your `SELECT` list to debug it http://rextester.com/DYDPOC85714

Answer (score 0):

I use a TVF to create dynamic date/time ranges.  Faster than a recursive cte and you define the date range, datepart, and increment

So for example:

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('20160911','20160917','DD',1)
```

Returns

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       2016-09-11 00:00:00.000
2       2016-09-12 00:00:00.000
3       2016-09-13 00:00:00.000
4       2016-09-14 00:00:00.000
5       2016-09-15 00:00:00.000
6       2016-09-16 00:00:00.000
7       2016-09-17 00:00:00.000
```

---

The UDF if interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```